# How to fetch result by MySql and Php if object_id is same

Tags: php, mysql, select

Values inserting in 3 table

**Table1: wp_terms**

[image]

**Table2: wp_term_taxonomy**

[image]

**Table3: wp_term_relationships**

[image]

I need ouput like this(i want fetch all brand and designer based on category)

[image]

I have tried this

```
$sql="select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_taxonomy where term_id=177";
mysql_query($sql);
```

I got output 251

But I am stuck in **Table3: wp_term_relationships** on how to fetch data where `object_id` are similar: 550, 540(for category, band, designer )

Answer (score 0):

I guess the query shd look like this:

```
SELECT m.name, t.taxanomy, t.description from wp_term_relationships r
INNER JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy t on r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms m on m.term_id=t.term_id  
WHERE (r.object_id=550 or  r.object_id=540) and t.term_id=177
```

Comment: i run that query but i only fetch category not brand and designer

Comment: Which table stored the brand and designer? i am a little bit confused. It would be better if you could fill the table with some meaningful data , so that easier for understanding.

Comment: wp_terms table insert brand shirt(term_id 176), designer vikas(term_id 175) and avi(term_id 180) after that wp_term_taxonomy insert brand shirt(term_taxonomy_id 250), desinger vikas(term_taxonomy_id 249) and avi(term_taxonomy_id 254)...........i have 1 brand shirt and two designer vikas and avi under category cloth1